# Using immutability-helper in typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutability, typescript-typings

I imported `update` from `@types/immutability-helper`. Now I want to push an item to the an array in a React's component state.

The syntax in `index.d.ts` file says:

```
interface UpdateFunction {
    (value: any[], spec: UpdateArraySpec): any[];
    (value: {}, spec: UpdateSpec): any;
    extend: (commandName: string, handler: CommandHandler) => any;
}
```

and `UpdateArraySpec` is

```
interface UpdateArraySpec extends UpdateSpecCommand {
    $push?: any[];
    $unshift?: any[];
    $splice?: any[][];
    [customCommand: string]: any;
}
```

does it mean I have to write 2 updates?:

```
this.setState(update(this.state, update(this.state.Markers, { $push: [info] })));
```

Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax that worked for me:

```
this.setState(update(this.state, { Markers: { $push: [info] } }));
```

This is not obvious from typescript definition file. But [the docs](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) says something like it.